# ProcessInstanceQuery not return result in second service task after exclusive Gateway in camunda

Tags: spring, camunda

I have a business with some service task that **exclusive Gateway** decide to switch between them. so for add another variables to process in next service task i need to query on camunda api in `orderBestProviders` but it does not return anything! see my code:

```
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void startProcess(MerchantRequestDto dto) {
        dto.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());

        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("modelId", dto.getId());
        map.put("input", dto);
        log.info(map.get("modelId"));
        runtimeService.createProcessInstanceByKey("SwitchEngine")
                .setVariables(map)
                .businessKey(switchProcessKey + dto.getId())
                .execute();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void orderBestProviders(String modelId) {
        Stack<Long> orderedProviders = new Stack<>();
        orderedProviders.push(10L);
        orderedProviders.push(1L);
        orderedProviders.push(2L);

        ProcessInstance instance = runtimeService.createProcessInstanceQuery()
                .processInstanceBusinessKey(switchProcessKey + modelId)
                .singleResult();

        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("providers", orderedProviders);
        map.put("providerExists", orderedProviders.size() > 0);

        String processInstanceId = instance.getProcessInstanceId();
        runtimeService.setVariables(
                processInstanceId, map
        );
    }
```

what is wrong?
is another way for resolve this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

base on transaction management in camunda ([see this link](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.15/user-guide/process-engine/transactions-in-processes/)), transaction not commit until the process see **[Wait States](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.15/user-guide/process-engine/transactions-in-processes/#wait-states)**, so i can not get process variables from query like this:

```
runtimeService.createProcessInstanceQuery()
                .processInstanceBusinessKey(switchProcessKey + modelId)
                .singleResult();
```

finally for resolve this problem I inject Execution in method and my problem resolved

```
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.runtime.Execution;

@Override
public void orderBestProviders(Execution execution) {
    Stack<Long> orderedProviders = new Stack<>();
    orderedProviders.push(10L);
    orderedProviders.push(1L);
    orderedProviders.push(2L);

    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("providers", orderedProviders);
    map.put("providerExists", orderedProviders.size() > 0);

    runtimeService.setVariables(
            execution.getId(), map
    );
}
```